# Compare array to database and change matching elements

Tags: vb.net, sorting, ms-access

I am working on a hospital database and I am loading hospital beds to combobox. What I want to do is, if bed is already taken, I want to add (Occupied) after id of bed.

There is a room and bed list table. Room 101 has Three beds. 1001, 1002 and 1003. I have loaded Bed_No to an array. **bed_ids_array()**

[image]

There is a Patient-Bed Occupied table. As you can see 1002 and 1003 are occupied by patients. I read this data through while loop **dr(1)**

[image]

**I am adding data to combobox in vb.net and it should look like this:**
[image]
**But it looks like this:**

[image]
(when rechecking with different values same data comes when data is being read from access database)

**The code I have used is this:**

```
       'Check if beds in array have patients
    Call connect()
    con.Open()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * from Bed_to_Patient_Relation", con)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        'Add all occupied stuff to combobox first
        For i = 0 To room_bed_count - 1
            'take first bed id and check all database
            If bed_ids_array(i) = dr(1) Then
                Cmbbx_Beds.Items.Add(bed_ids_array(i) & "Occupied")
            Else
                Cmbbx_Beds.Items.Add(bed_ids_array(i))
            End If
        Next
    End While
```

What I want to do is to add **"Occupied"** to text if match is found, else, just enter normally

Comment: you might start by clearing the combobox instead of adding to it over and over.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making a few changes. Ditch the combobox for a datagridview. You can still select the row you want, but have better visibility of the data. Join your two tables in the query to identify which beds are available or occupied. Include the bed and room id in the patient to bed relationship table, or better yet, assign a unique id for each bed. An occupied table may allow for a more effective join.

The issue I think you have with existing code is that you're adding the list twice, or not clearing it after each reload of the box. I find it much more efficient to populate a grid based on data from a query, such as the join mentioned above.

probably not the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Actually that was exactly what I was hoping for. Database arrangement should make for less code. You are right.
Question1: By join do you mean use sql join and then get data to vb.net
Question2:  You told to "Include the bed and room id in the patient to bed relationship table. "                                           Wouldnt that result in redundant data. That is what I was trying to avoid

Comment: Yes, sql join. you can add strings, in the query, to show occupied in the grid, if you go that route. you are correct. I thought the beds were 1001-1003 for each room. The beds are unique, which is what you want. my mistake there.

Comment: Database arrangement CAN result in less code, but you have to actually use data objects like DataTables, DataSets and so forth.  COPYING data  to arrays, then COPYING again to UI controls is part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks to both I have checked answer as useful but cant select it as it is not the answer to the question. Hope someone will give the answer and I will select it.

Comment: The issue is how your arriving at your count, which is ambiguous. I suggest you make changes based on suggestions, and then post an update (edit your post) and see if you can help you then. I can't help you on this path, and I'm sure no one else will either. Its just a very odd way to approach this. You should omit the underscores, follow .Net naming patterns, and use a proper select statement. The answer in simple terms is to add combobox.items.clear before populating the combobox.